# Is it possible to run a php code on every html file using htaccess, or similar?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So i made a site that allows users to create their own site, with stuff like wysiswyg editors etc.
When they register they get an url like user.site.com
and they can create files, folders, upload files etc, they can create and edit html files, example if someone created index.html = user.site.com/index.html they can edit that with my site tools, and access it through user.site.com/index.html, i just want to know if i can append a php code to all the html files they create without actually adding content to the file.
Like

echo 'Created with AppName';

would automatically be added to all the html files  that every user created without actually being inside it, can htaccess do this?

Comment: rewrite the URLs to automatically go through a script of your choosing.

Comment: no it has to run with the html files, so i can dynamically manage content etc with javascript, php etc

Comment: then fetch the files based on the URL...

Comment: Considering you have three answers answering three different questions, you may want to take some time to think about what you are trying to accomplish and rephrase this question with a bit more care.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse HTML as PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181853/parse-html-as-php)

Answer (score 1):

Just that all the pages that users send are rotated based on another php file.

Assuming the user (assuming the User's name is `john`) sent the file `foo.html`

to access the file `foo.php` need to go to a URL like this:

`john.site.com/partners.php?path=foo.html` **[fixed]**

With `.htaccess (mod rewrite)`, you can modify this `URL` making it look like this:

`john.site.com/foo.html`

just the subdomain has access to php file `partners.php` (which should be the root)

**mod_rewrite/.htaccess**:
http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

---

**[edited]**

Example:

*.htaccess:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\/\-_. ]+)$ /partners.php?path=$1
```

*PHP code:*

```
include('youscript.php');

//Get username
$tmp = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$tmp = explode('.',$Q);
$username = $test[0];

//Print file in page
if(isset('users/'.$username.'/'.$_GET['path'])){
  echo file_get_contents('users/'.$username.'/'.$_GET['path']);
}
```

**Results:**

`paul.site.com/partners.php?path=mypage.html`

to

`paul.site.com/mypage.html`

---

`john.site.com/partners.php?path=folder1/mypage.html`

to

`john.site.com/folder1/mypage.html`

---

`william.site.com/partners.php?path=css/style.css`

to

`paul.site.com/css/style.css`

Comment: The problem is that i already made it like this http://user.site.com/index.html <--- index.html is created by the user

Comment: Yes, you can do this, see I edited my answer. Just as the subdomain has access to `.htaccess`

Comment: Its not accessed like that, if they create file.html it is directly at user.site.com/site.html

Comment: I added "path" as an example, since you said they can create folders. If you do so: `john.site.com/partners?path=foo.html` you can access so `john.site.com/foo.html` (with ".htaccess")

Comment: I know how/what your are saying but thats not what im trying to do

Comment: I edited my answer, I added an example of php.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is that you want to have your web server process `.htm` or `.html` files for `php` code. Is that correct? If so, you'll probably want to do something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Simply put, this will tell Apache to process .html and .htm files for php code (if any).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

Comment: The app will allow users to create their own html, js files etc... i just want to know if i can somehow append a php code to all the files that was created

Comment: This will add the php code at "runtime", and won't actually edit the user's file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to edit your php.ini, you can use `auto_prepend_file`. This is not accessible from `.htaccess`, but otherwise achieves what you are trying to do:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

From the manual:

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used.
>
> The special value none disables auto-prepending.

This will allow you to run a specified PHP file before each request.

Note if you're wanting to run this on HTML files, not just PHP, you will also need to set a handler to run those files through PHP, as mentioned above:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: If this answer isn't exactly right for you, try this variant

**.htaccess:**
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .html .htm`

**php.ini**
`auto_append_file = '/home/[MY USER'S USERERNAME]/public_html/sub_footer.php'`

Answer (score 0):

You mean like using a include command?

Try this:

```
<?php
include 'yourphpscript.php';
?>
```

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Yes i mean like that but without actually adding the include("script.php"); to the files they create, they can create html files

Comment: I haven't heard of such a thing. Usually people include things at the beginning (or end) of their scripts anyway, so it isn't that hard to add in the include. I haven't ever heard of anyone using .htaccess to do that, but that doesn't mean it isn't possible.

Comment: The app will allow users to create their own html, js files etc... i just want to know if i can somehow append a php code to all the files that was created... so it will be user.site.com/filecreatedbyuser.html, i hope you all understand what i mean :)