# Why won't my function include work?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to include other page from other folder. and i tried this and it won't show the "side.php"

```
<?php
include 'side.php';
?>
```

And the "side.php" has:

```
<a href="/index.html">home</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to side.php is correct? You said it's in another folder.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before the include.

Comment: It's unclear what youre' asking here because you haven't showed your directory layout. -1

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the answer to your question inside your question.

> " *Im trying to include other page from other folder*"

It means that you have to go inside that folder in order to access the file

```
<?php
include 'folder_name/side.php'
?>
```

or just copy the *side.php* file where your working file is so that all files are in one place

Maybe I'm wrong because I don't know php so it might not work but you could check this out 
[Include PHP file into HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105029/include-php-file-into-html-file)