# How to insert this code into HTML file?

Tags: html

I've been given this code for my registration page:

```
<div id=mainsection>

<? $row = getcustomerdetails(); ?>

<h1>Customer Information</h1>

<? if ($error) echo "<p class='error'>You have an error in your form - please fix the issues below:</p>".$error; ?>

<p>Your contact details will be used to assign the legal owner of any domains you register, and where necessary to verify your payment information. <b>If there are any errors in the form you will not be able to complete your purchase.</b></p>

<form method='post'>

<h3>Contact Information</h3>

<table>

<tbody>

<tr><th>Salutation</th><td> <? echo salutation(); ?> </td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo req(firstname); ?>><th>First Name(s)</th><td><? echo forminput('firstname'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD>

</tr>

<tr <? echo req(lastname); ?>><th>Surname</th><td><? echo forminput('lastname'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr><th>Organisation Type</th><td> <? echo orgtype(); ?> </td></tr>

<tr <? if ($row[orgtype]=="Company") echo req(orgname); ?>><th>Organisation Name</th><td><? echo forminput('orgname'); ?></td><TD>Required for companies</TD></tr>

<script type='text/javascript'>

toggle_org_name();

</script>

<tr <? echo req(address1); ?>><th>First Line of Address</th><td><? echo forminput('address1'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr><th>Second Line of Address</th><td><? echo forminput('address2'); ?></td></tr>

<tr <? echo req(city); ?>><th>Town</th><td><? echo forminput('city'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo req(county); ?>><th>County</th><td><? echo forminput('county'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo req(postcode); ?>><th>Postcode</th><td><? echo forminput('postcode'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo req(country); ?>><th>Country</th><td> <? echo formcountry(); ?> </td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo reqphone(phonedefault); ?>><th>Telephone Number</th><td><? echo forminput('phonedefault'); ?><TD>Required - must be in the format +44.2081234567</TD></td></tr>

<tr <? echo reqphone(phonemobile); ?>><th>Mobile Number</th><td><? echo forminput('phonemobile'); ?></td><td>Must be in the format +44.71234567</td></tr>

<tr><th>Fax Number</th><td><? echo forminput('fax'); ?></td></tr>

<tr <? if ($_POST && !checkEmail($row[email])) echo "style='background:red'"; ?>><th>Email Address</th><td><? echo forminput('email'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

</tbody>

</table>

<h3>Security information</h3>

<table class='left-th'>

<tbody>

<tr <? echo pass(password1); ?>><th>Password</th><td><? echo formpassword('password1'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo pass(password2); ?>><th>Confirm Password</th><td><? echo formpassword('password2'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr  <? if ($_POST && !checkdate($row[dobm],$row[dobd],$row[doby])) echo "style='background:red'"; ?>><th>Date of Birth</th><td>

<? echo dobd(); ?> / <? echo dobm(); ?> / <? echo doby(); ?>

</td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

<tr <? echo req(securityquestion); ?>><th>Choose a Security Question</th><td> <? echo securityquestion(); ?> </td></tr>

<tr <? echo req(securityanswer); ?>><th>Choose a Security Answer</th><td><? echo forminput('securityanswer'); ?></td><TD>Required</TD></tr>

</tbody>

</table>

<h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>

<p <? if ($_POST && !$_POST[terms]) echo "style='background:red'"; ?>><input type='checkbox' name='terms' value='1' /> Please click here to indicate that you accept

<a href='tandc' target='_blank'>our terms and conditions</a>.</p>

<p><input type='submit' value='<?

if ($_GET[noupsell]==1) echo "Update Details"; else echo "Register Now"?>' /></p>

</form>

</div>
```

I'm trying to use this with a template I have. The template looks like this, how can I, if at all possible, use the above code within this HTML file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Web Hosting | Support</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.js" ></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script src="js/Shanti_400.font.js"></script>
<script src="js/Didact_Gothic_400.font.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">.button1{behavior:url("js/PIE.htc");}</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page5">
<div class="body1">
  <div class="body2">
    <div class="main">
      <!-- header -->
      <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <ul id="icons">
            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/icon1.gif" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon2.gif" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="contacts.html"><img src="images/icon3.gif" alt=""></a></li>
          </ul>
          <span class="call">Need Help? Please email or call <span>1-800-345-5894</span></span> </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">Web Hosting</a></h1>
          <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
              <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="hosting.html">Hosting</a></li>
              <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li id="menu_active"><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <span id="slogan1">Simple<span>Clever</span><span>Effective</span></span> </header>
      <!-- / header -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <!-- content -->
  <section id="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <article class="col3">



        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- / content  -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <!-- / footer -->
  <footer>Copyright &copy; <a href="#">Domain Name</a> All Rights Reserved<br>
    Design by <a target="_blank" href="http://www.templatemonster.com/">TemplateMonster.com</a></footer>
  <!-- / footer -->
</div>
<script>Cufon.now();</script>
<div align=center>This template  downloaded form <a href='http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/'>free website templates</a></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from simply pasting it in?

Comment: I've copied it into the content but it doesn't recognize the php and file writes it as text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `<?php ?>`, you need to rename your .html file into a .php file otherwise the server won't recognize when you use code.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've tried that before but it makes almost everything disappear.. you can see what I mean here: http://greensourcehosting.com/signup.php, the header etc is all there but no register form or footer. Thanks.

Comment: I understand your issue, I've found an answer that may fix your problem ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/20105271/4884034  you need to create a .htaccess file and add the lines mentioned in this comment

Comment: Thanks Daniel. The .htaccess file is already there so I added the line and it still doesn't work. Should the file be .php? It may be how I've added them together... how would you add the two files above together?

Comment: The problem with templates is it sometimes becomes tricky to add custom code.. I think I would create a new index.php file and I'd split this html file into multiple files like "header.html" "footer.html" and then I'd just include them step by step in my php by writing "include_once header.html" this way it could be easier to know where your html is getting troubles to fix it

Comment: Thanks again. Perhaps I'm in over my head. That include_once loaded the HTML but ignored the php in the file.

Comment: @dingdong6 Your opening tags should start `<?php` unless you have set the `short_open_tag` setting