# Importing contents from 1 html to another html file

Tags: css, html

Is is possible to import contents from one html file into another by using just plain HTML or CSS? JavaScript or jQuery is **NOT** an option, I want to be able import contents of a file if JavaScript is disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: not possible. if JS is disabled, you can look into using PHP

Comment: If HTML is rendered on the server, use server-side code to do it is simple.

Comment: For a bit of context, please briefly explain why you want to import HTML or a brief outline of what you are hoping to achieve. For example, are you wanting to put common elements like a Nav bar in one file?

Comment: @noob, careful with the term "rendered", it can be ambiguous here... you could be referring to server side code generating HTML **or** the browser "rendering" the HTML and CSS to visual (or audio if using a screen reader) elements.

Comment: @JonP is right. I should say *generate HTML*

Answer (score 0):

Checkout HTML5 imports via [Html5rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) and at polymer-project

For example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to use JavaScript to import the contents of the imported file. I'm trying to figure it out without using JavaScript or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to render the HTML server side, ie, via PHP or server side JS. Since most server readily supports PHP, you can simply change both your HTML file extension to .php and insert a php include tag. ([Include PHP file into HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105029/include-php-file-into-html-file)).