# Cannot load PHP inside HTML webpage

Tags: php, html, include

I am taking a Web Design and Management class and the professor basically wants us to upload a website into the university's student server. I have done websites before, but he wants us to incorporate PHP in it, for which I have virtually no experience. I wrote a page, `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>

    <?php include('../includes/header.php') ?>
    <?php include('../includes/menu.php') ?>
    <?php include('../includes/lsidebar.php') ?>
    <?php include('../includes/rsidebar.php') ?>
    <?php include('../includes/home.php') ?>

</html>
```

Once I uploaded this file, along with all the pertaining ones (header.php, menu.php, lsidebar.php, rsidebar.php, and home.php all with some `html` content), and change proper file permissions to 755, I opened the space reserved for me in the server to find the index page was blank!

I e-mailed the professor about this, and he said I should place this line as my first line in the file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

I ran the site again, and the page only displays the above line. How can I enable PHP commands to be recognized inside an HTML file?

Thank you very much for any assistance in advance!

Comment: *"I wrote a page, index.html"* - then do *"I wrote a page, index.php"* and it will work ;-) or instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: remember to close these off too `<?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>` it's just good practice.

Comment: I forgot to add that, but I tried this in both `index.html` and `index.php` and I get the same error

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as @FoX commented before, you have to add the `.php` extension to your files in order to run `PHP` code on the server side. If you add `.html` extension, `PHP code` is not capable to run on the server side.

**EDIT**: Unless you configurate your server to do it in that way, as @Fred-ii- suggested in his comment. In that case, you will have to edit the `.htaccess` file (Apache) or the `web.config` file in (Windows IIS server) to treat `.html` files as `.php`.

He also suggested another option, that one was based on header modification through `httpd.conf` file in Apache. I attach the links he provided me:

https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/

[Parse HTML as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181853/parse-html-as-php)

In addition, your code will debug `Fatals errors` due the fact that each line must end with a `;`

```
<?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/menu.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/lsidebar.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/rsidebar.php'); ?>
<?php include('../includes/home.php'); ?>
```

I would suggest you to take a look at the basics concepts of the PHP at the W3Schools website:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: *"If you add .html extension, PHP code is not capable to run on the server side (Obviously)."* - Untrue. Read [my second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305705/cannot-load-php-inside-html-webpage#comment48706780_30305705) to the OP.

Comment: That's fair, I forgot to add, "_unless you use `.htaccess` or `web.config` on your server in order to treat `.html` files as `.php`_" :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: It should be added to your answer. Plus, here's a Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/7181853/ that shows a few other options. Another page https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/

Comment: Thanks for the links! I usually use `mod_rewrite` to deal with that kind of situations. It's good to know another option. As you suggested, I edited the answer @Fred-ii-